# Migrate from windows 10 to linux for begginers

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, partitioning, windows-10

I'm tired of windows and more tired of windows 10 and all its updates all the time. I need help to migrate from windows to any version linux distribution, i think ubuntu is okay. I'm spanish speaker, so it's a bit difficult to me to find exactly what i want. Below i put i list of what i want to do and it would be very helpful if someone could help me to find any post from this forum or article which could help me.

1. Make a copy of hardaware drivers. Is it necessary?
2. Erase hard disk partitions. My computer actually has 2 partitions one for windows 10 and another for an ubuntu version. When windows uploaded to windows 10, 1 or 2 years ago, ubuntu's partition dissapeared. So i want to erase everything and start from zero.
3. Install any ubuntu's version. I use my computer for universities purposes and i also work a lot using python and anaconda.

Well, i wish someone have patience and could help me with my goal. haha. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Well, it's very easy to format and set up a new ubuntu distro. And windows hardware drivers cannot run on Linux. It is not to worry about drivers as ubuntu comes with all basic drivers. You can follow [link](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop) for installation.

Comment: Thank you very much!! i'm done. I thought it was more difficult. Once a friend installed this for me i and i got the sense that i needed to do all the steps i mentionated above. Thanks again!!